# Temperature and oxygen levels 1 mile below Antarctica's surface

Tags: internal-consistency, ice, polar-region

If people were able to travel to a cave 1 mile below the surface in Antarctica, how long would it take before they suffocated (both if there was a hole at the surface and if that hole were to become blocked)? How long would it take before hypothermia set in? If it were an area of geothermal heat, would it be possible for someone to survive in such a cave for 24 hours? One more question: How long would it take to drill a 1-mile deep borehole into Antarctica ice?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Do take a moment to check out our [tour] and [help] --- you'll find lots of information there that will help you write queries that are a good fit for this forum.  As it stands, you're asking too many questions. SE uses a *one focused question gets on point answers* model. I count three or four questions here! Second, the questions you're asking lack sufficient detail to answer sensibly. E.g., suffocation will be matter of volume of trapped air along with the presence of openings & air flow. You need to provide those details. Thirdly, we don't answer straight up math questions.

Comment: If it's a matter of plugging values into an equation, this isn't the best kind of question to ask here! Fourthly, this forum exists to help you devise your own fictional world. This is more a series of real world questions that might best be addressed elsewhere. We'd love to help you out with your own fictional world.

Comment: Sorry! Thank you for helping me to understand what is appropriate.

Comment: Your questions are good, but we need you to have one question per post. As it is you risk getting it closed for needing more focus. Please split your questions into different posts, then we'll try to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are cave systems on earth that are even deeper. So you can take a look at them:

[Krubera Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krubera_Cave): Going deeper in the cave may result in warmer tempterature due to the [geothermal gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient) or vulcanic activity depending on the origins of the cave. So it's possible (and likely) to have liquid water in it. It's really likely, that they are flooded and you need diver equipment in order not to suffocate.

This [Article](https://www.livescience.com/62983-thai-soccer-team-human-survival-caves.html) says, that oxygen is not a problem in caves (in general), but you may find CO2 pockets (where you obviously can't breathe).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As temperature increases with depth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient
the temperature 1 mile below Antarctica would be quite tolerable and might even be warm so no hypothermia.

The amount of oxygen available would depend on the size of the hole through which it came in and the potential for a draft to form. Survival time would also depend on the size of the chamber they were in.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great. I appreciate it.